# Creating dropdown option when setting up Python script into ArcToolbox?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, choice-list

I created a script that I will import to an ArcToolbox. On the display name section, I have asked the user to choose a workspace, select the shapefile, field name, and an option to make a pdf, jpeg or none.

For the last option, instead of making the user write whether they want pdf, jpeg, or none, is there an option where I can create a dropdown menu with the 3 selection?

Answer (score 2):

As commented by [@hornbydd](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171255/creating-dropdown-option-when-setting-up-python-script-into-arctoolbox/257194#comment255625_171255) and [@John](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171255/creating-dropdown-option-when-setting-up-python-script-into-arctoolbox/257194#comment255640_171255):

> Set the parameter to be of type TEXT then when you are in the
>   properties dialog of the script tool you can create a LIST of values
>   in the FILTER property of that parameter.

and

> Multi-value, lists, filters, ranges, etc.
>   http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/creating-tools/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm